# Codeigniter: Unique phone number check in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am facing an issue with the checking of a unique phone number present in the database. On submit it detects each number I enter as number found in the database, even if it doesn't exist. Attaching the code below:

**AJAX**

```
<script>
function checkdata(){
var tel = $('.tel').val();      
var x;
if(tel){
$.ajax({
   url: '<?php echo base_url('index.php/admin/customer/check_phone_availibility1'); ?>',
   data:{tel:tel},
   error: function() {
  alert("An error has occurred.");
   },
   success: function(data) {   
    x= data;

    },
   type: 'POST'
});
if(!x){
alert('This phone exists in database');
$('.tel').val("");
return false;
}
}
}   
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public function check_phone_availibility1(){
$tel = $this->input->post('tel');
$success = $this->customer_m->check_phone_no_availability($tel);
if($success){
    echo true;
}
else {
    echo false;
} 
 }
```

**MODEL**

```
public function check_phone_no_availability($phone){
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * from customers WHERE phone='$phone'"); 
$phone = $query->result();

if(count($phone))
{
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}       

}
```

**VIEW**

```
<input type="text" name="phone" value="" class="form-control tel" id="phone" maxlength="10" required="">
<input type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="Save Customer" class="btn btn-success" onclick="return checkdata();">
```

I will be really grateful if this issue can be sorted out. Thanks

Comment: try `if(count($phone) > 0)`

Comment: Hey, I will try it out at get back to you

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = false;
$var2 = '';
$var3 = null;
```

produces

```
count($var) => 1
count($var) => 1
count($var) => 0
```

so, in your model you can check if your query generated any result, you can do something like this:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * from customers WHERE phone='$phone'"); 
$query_result= $query->result();

return (count($query_result) > 1) ? true : false;
```

or, just

```
return ($query_result) ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with some modifications:

**Controller**

```
public function check_phone_availibility1(){
$tel = $this->input->post('tel');
$success = $this->customer_m->check_phone_no_availability($tel);
if($success->num_rows() == 0){
  echo 1;
}
else {
  echo 0;
} 
}
```

**Model**

```
public function check_phone_no_availability($phone){
return $this->db->query("SELECT * from customers WHERE phone='$phone'"); 
}
```

**AJAX**

```
<script>
function checkdata(){
var tel = $('.tel').val();      
var x;
if(tel){
$.ajax({ url: '<?php echo base_url('index.php/admin/customer/check_phone_availibility1'); ?>',
data:{tel:tel},
error: function() {
alert("An error has occurred.");
},
success: function(data) {   
 x= data;

 },
type: 'POST'
});
if(x != "1"){
alert('This phone exists in database');
$('.tel').val("");
return false;
}
}
}   
</script>
```

Comment: It is still showing phone number exists even in the case of a new number being added

Comment: Try to evaluate and echo your query using echo $this->db->last_query(); just paste it after your $success variable. And then paste your query to your sql console or whatever you used

Answer (score 0):

```
if(count($phone) > 0)
{
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}
```

you need to check if the return is greater than 0, since if will return true if the value is not null or false

Comment: It doesn't submit, but even if the number doesn't exist it still displays 'The phone number exists in the database'